# how to solve this half diamond pattern problem with alphabets , Start from A and go till O downwards in inter loop

Tags: c++

OMJFA

NKGB

LHC

ID

E

---

---

My code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char ch = 'O';

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            cout << ch;
            ch--;

            if (ch < 'A') {
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actual Output:

ONMLK

JIHG

FED

CB

A

Do i need to use any additional loop or use any condition with j

i tried with j==n but it will need j from n to i

N is user input

Comment: what is "this pattern problem" ? To get the desired output you can do `std::cout << "OMJFA\nNKGB\nLHC\nID\nE\n";`. I suppose the exercise asks for something else, what is it?

Comment: If you output char by char you need to calculate how many chars actually to skip. First row is yet pretty simple, each following character skips one letter more, but each following one gets more complicated. A totally different, but pretty simple approach would be filling strings with characters, e.g. for five rows as in your example append consecutive letters first first to all five, then to four, then ... strings (loop from 5 downwards until reaching 0). Then reverse the strings and output them.

Comment: @Aconcagua sure I can guess what the code is supposed to do, but the details are unclear. OP starts always with `O`, they dont mention the role of `n`. Explaining what the code should do in all details is more than half way to writing the code.

Comment: In this code we need to print alphabets from A to O going downwards in jth row or inner loop that is the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it all at once. You can first prepare the output in a vector of strings, then printing it is a simple loop.

Also it helps to consider how you would do it with pen and paper. I would do the following: I would start with the letter `'A'` in the first row. Then I would increment the character and continue with the next `n` rows. This I can repeat, but on each pass I skip one more row at the end, and the additional characters are prepended to the rows.

And thats exactly what you can write down in code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n_rows;
    std::cin >> n_rows;
    char ch = 'A';
    std::vector<std::string> rows(n_rows);
    for (int i=0;i<n_rows;++i) {
        for (int row=0;row<n_rows-i;++row) {
            rows[row].insert(0,1,ch);
            ++ch;
        }
    }
    for (const auto& r : rows) {
        std::cout << r << "\n";
    }
}
```

Inserting to the front of a string is a rather inefficient operation, thats why `std::string` does not offer a method that does it directly. Though, we can use `insert(0,1,ch);` to insert `1` character with value `ch` at position `0`.

I suggest you to try this code first. Its the most simple I can imagine for this task. Next you can try to rearrange the code in such a way that you append the characters to the end of the strings. Next you can try to get rid of the `std::vector<std::string>` and produce the output directly. For each step, you should again take pen and paper and make a plan of what steps the code must take to get the desired output. Only when you have a plan, start to write the code.